# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; Hiding Content

Tags: html, ios, css

Yesterday, I posted about items not displaying when they are `positioned: absolute;` on iOS Safari, however, I have narrowed down the problem. It is not the positioning of the items that causes the items to disappear, it is the WebKit inertia scrolling CSS selector:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

***Here is my goal:
I am trying to make a table that has the left column fixed in position, and the other columns scrollable. Without the webkit css selector, the scrollbar does not appear, and the scrolling does not have inertia.
Is there a way to accomplish this? I would like to only have one table if possible.***

With WebKit CSS Selector: (left column does not display)

[image: screenshot1]

Without WebKit CSS Selector: (left column displays, but inertia scrolling and scroll bars are not visible)
[image: screenshot2]

Without `WebKit` CSS Selector: http://jakeserver.com/Uploads/StackOverflow/scrollTable-NoWebKitCSS.html

With `WebKit` CSS Selector: http://jakeserver.com/Uploads/StackOverflow/scrollTable-WebKitCSS.html

Comment: Can you post the full code? Hard to debug with one line of CSS!

Comment: @speak Thanks for your reply. Can you access the links at the end of the post?

Comment: Hey Jake, did you find the solution of this issue? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @jeewan No, unfortunately I never found a solution. If you up-vote it, maybe it will get more attention.

Comment: up-voted :-)
Is it a bug in iOS itself or we can fix this issue from css by ourselves?

Comment: @jeewan My best guess is that this is a WebKit rendering error/bug. It may be possible to create a workaround.

Comment: Hey Jake, let me know if you find the solution for this issue. I could not fix this in my application and I am thinking to remove the web kit scroll touch.